# How to loop program so it continues execution

Tags: c++, loops

I currently have this code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <curl.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include "boost\timer.hpp"


int main(void)
{
    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res;
    boost::timer t;

    int number = 1;

    while (number == 1)
    {
         if(t.elapsed() > 10)
         {
            curl = curl_easy_init();
            if(curl) 
            {
                curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://google.com");
                res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

                /* always cleanup */ 
                curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
            } 
            t.restart();
         }
      }
}
```

What i'd like it to do is continue execution of this program and never end until someone closes the window.
I tried the aforementioned code, however CPU usage spiked to 25% on my quad core CPU.

So how do i continue the execution of the program and loop the code within the while without using so much CPU?

P.S
25% on a quad core means 100% cpu usage on a single core CPU.

Comment: Well, this is called "busy waiting", and that's why your CPU spiked to 25%. You need to program using an event-driven framework instead (Whether that is Windows Forms, MFC, WPF, Qt, ... etc. Pick your poison.)

Comment: "25% on a quad core means 100% cpu usage on a single core CPU" - not necessarily; was it 25% across all 4 cores?

Comment: By the way, if you want an endless loop you can use `while(1)` or (more idiomatic) `for(;;)`, without using that useless `number` variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Sleep(10000)` to pause program execution for approx. 10 seconds. You can drop the `boost::timer` - just sleep 10 seconds in each loop iteration (Sleep is not as accurate, but for 10 seconds the inaccuracy should be negligible).

Your code is what is called a 'busy loop' - for the CPU it makes no difference whether you hang around in a tight loop without much work or do heavy computations. Both will use 100% of a CPU core because there's an neverending stream of instructions coming in. To use less, you need to relinquish execution for a while to let the OS execute other processes.

Comment: Unfortunately, No matter what i tried, visual studio would not recognize Sleep as a valid function...undefined reference, that is why i couldn't do it. Otherwise that was my first thought

Comment: Oh, it seems in visual studio it is spelled with a capital "S". Thank you guys for pointing that out!

Comment: That's not Visual Studio, it's the Windows API, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686298(v=vs.85).aspx for more details.

Comment: Well i did include the windows.h header because sleep didn't work and when i searched for a solution it was hinted to use it.
But i had no idea it was spelled with a capital "S".

Answer (score 2):

What you're currently doing is *busy waiting*. That is, even though your program doesn't need to do anything, it's still keeping that loop spinning, waiting for the timer. What you need to do is to execute a true sleep, which tells your operating system that the process doesn't need to do anything for the next 10 seconds.

One way to do a true sleep in boost is the [boost::this_thread::sleep](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html#thread.thread_management.this_thread.sleep) function.

Answer (score 1):

If need to slow it down with some `sleep()`.  Basically you need to put your thread to sleep to allow other processes to execute.

Answer (score 1):

What you've implemented is called a busy wait and is considered very bad style. Use `sleep` to suspend program execution for a short time, and write an eternal loop as:

```
for (;;)
```

or

```
while (true)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to do a sleep after each  operations.

Answer (score 0):

You can `boost::threads` to run it in it's own thread and then do a thread.join in the main thread to wait for it.  If the other thread never ends, because of a `while(true)` then you program will run until you close the window.

Comment: Even if you move it in a separate thread it will remain a "busy waiting" loop that eats the CPU.

Answer (score 0):

Call [`SwitchToThread()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686352%28VS.85%29.aspx) inside of your `while` loop. (`Sleep` is less than ideal, as it forfeits the current time slice even if no other thread needs it.)

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a timer instead of doing such a tight loop.
Alternatively you can put a System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(300) in between.

Someone would have to kill your process to close it, I cannot discern any window in your code.

If you are polling a website (it looks like you are doing something with Google there) then I would advise you to make a much larger interval! Not many a web-master would be happy to see such activity. It's more likely to be seen as a DOS-attack!

Any way, if there's a window, rather put this code in a timer delegate, otherwise start a timer and allow the user to exit your program somehow (maybe with Console.ReadKey() or so).